# sp_send_dbmail - Assistance please

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL newbie. I have several jobs sending query results via email, all working fine. I'm having trouble with this last one and am not sure what is wrong. The dbmailprofile works fine and the receipients are fine. The query works if I run it in SSMS but it doesn't work if I try to create a email job. I changed the @recipients to a generic term and change the query to not show anything specific. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
USE msdb
EXECUTE AS USER = 'dbo'
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'dbmailprofile',
    @recipients = 'username@someone.com',
    @query =  ' SELECT A.DOCNUMBER as DocumentNumber,P.DOCNAME as DocumentName,A.TYPIST as UserSystemID,PP.USER_ID as UserID,PP.FULL_NAME as UserFullName,A.ACTIVITY_TYPE as ActivityCode,
AT.DESCRIPTION as ActivityDescription, CAST(DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), START_DATE) AS varchar(64)) 
AS 'ActivityTime In Local Time'
FROM DOCSADM.ACTIVITYLOG A
JOIN DOCSADM.PROFILE P
ON A.DOCNUMBER=P.DOCNUMBER
JOIN DOCSADM.PEOPLE PP
ON A.TYPIST=PP.SYSTEM_ID
JOIN DOCSADM.ACT_TYPES AT
ON A.ACTIVITY_TYPE=AT.VALUE
WHERE PP.USER_ID = 'USER'
AND A.START_DATE 
> DATEADD(DD, -1,GETDATE())
GROUP BY A.DOCNUMBER,P.DOCNAME,A.TYPIST,PP.USER_ID,PP.FULL_NAME,
A.ACTIVITY_TYPE,AT.DESCRIPTION,A.START_DATE ORDER BY A.DOCNUMBER DESC, A.START_DATE DESC;',
    @subject = 'Activity Report',
    @body = 'The Stored Procedure completed sucessfully' ,
```

When I run this, I get the error 'Incorrect syntax near 'ActivityTime'

Comment: When a literal string has a `'` in it, you must escape it (double it up) `''`. I.e. `'...AS ''ActivityTime In Local Time''...'`.

Comment: On a different note, if you want to quote an object (or alias) you're *normally* better off using brackets (`[]`). They are the delimit Identifier characters for T-SQL. [Classes of Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15#classes-of-identifiers)

Comment: Better to use [ActivityTime In Local Time] instead of the single quotes.

Comment: Thanks. I added the additional ' to ActivityTime In Local Time but now get Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.

Comment: I tried  [ActivityTime In Local Time] as well but still getting the Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0 message.

Comment: You have multiple string literals that need to be escaped. But you are biting off more than you can chew. Step one is to write and verify your select query using a query window in SSMS. When that runs without errors, add it to your question and others can help. I'll point out that you use a group by clause without any aggregates. That suggests a logical flaw in the query that you are attempting to cover up with the group by clause. And don't use DD for the date part - just use DAY. That is far more readable and less likely to be confused by anyone reading your code.